# Vector of lists

Tags: c++, list, vector

So I am trying to write a function that takes two arguments, `list<item> myList`, and `int num_items` and creates a vector of new lists. Each item has data member ID, which is the index in the vector of which list the item should be added to.  The ID of any item is guaranteed to be no greater than (num_items - 1). Here is my code:

```
vector<list<item>> createVector(list<item> myList, int num_items) {
   vector<list<item>> myVector;
   myVector.reserve(num_items);

   for(item& i : myList)
      myVector[i.ID].push_back(i);

   return myVector;
}
```

This is causing a segmentation fault whenever I try to call push_back() to add an item to a list in the vector.  I know how to implement the function using pointers, however the type returned by the function must be an actual vector of lists not pointers to them, so I can't use dynamic memory allocation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`reserve()` merely allocates a block of memory. It does not create the `list` objects that you are calling `push_back()` on.  You need to use `resize()` instead of `reserve()` to create them:

```
myVector.resize(num_items);
```

Or better, pass the count to the constructor directly instead:

```
vector<list<item>> myVector(num_items);
```

Answer (score 0):

`reserve` only reserves space for that many vector elements; it doesn't create any elements, so you can't access them. You want to use `resize` (or just pass the size as a constructor argument), to populate the vector with valid, empty lists.